# Get form content from iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, forms, iframe

I have a form, 2 questions are in separate iFrames, these options change depending on what options are chosen on the parent frame (they auto refresh when certain options are chosen), how can I get the option chosen in the iFrames back in to the parent frame to pass on when the form is submitted?
Parent snippet:

```
<td>Manager Name:</td>
<td><iframe name="manname" id="manname" frameborder="0" width="300" height="21" scrolling="no" src="./get_manager.php"></iframe>
<input type="hidden" id="starter_manname" name="starter_manname" width="300">
</td>
```

I'm wanting `starter_manname` to contain what is chosen from the iFrame. This is part of the iFrame content:

```
<select id="starter_manname" name="starter_manname" width="300" class="textboxstyle">
<option selected value="">----- Select Manager -----</option>
<option value="CouldBeAnythingVal">CouldBeAnythingName</option>
</select>
```

the iFrames just contain the `<html>`, `<body>` &  `<option>` tags, there's no `<form>` or anything in there. I'm useless with Javascript and I assume that's the answer so if you can explain the answer or point me in the correct direction it would be appreciated (without jQuery though please)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the iframe contents using jquery's .contents() method.
If you have an iframe with id "myframe"
then, you can do:

```
    $('#myframe').contents().find('something')
    // or event bind events
    $('#myframe').contents().find('button').on('click', function(){  });
```

Assuming that you have content inside iframe `<iframe name="manname" id="manname" frameborder="0" width="300" height="21" scrolling="no" src="./get_manager.php"></iframe>`

```
$(function(){
  var selectInframe = $('#manname').contents().find('#starter_manname');
  selectInframe.on('change', function(){
    var new_val = $(this).val();
    $('#starter_manname').val(starter_manname);
  });
});
```

without jquery you can you contentDocument

```
var selectInframe = document.getElementById('manname');
var selectInframeDocument = selectInframe.contentDocument;
// selectInframeDocument is the document form your iframe
// you can do selectInframeDocument.getElementByTagName('..') etc to access elements and bind
```

Hope you get it.

Comment: Thanks, any way to do it without JQuery?